Is there a geometric interpretation of symmetric powers of vectors?
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, over the real numbers to fix ideas. If we pick an inner product then the classical image of a vector in $V$ is a directed arrow. If $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are vectors in $V$ then we can interpret the wedge product $v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ as the oriented parallelogram formed by the vectors; a general element of $\bigwedge^k V$ is then a linear combination of those.
How about the symmetric powers $\operatorname{Sym}^k V$? Is there some way of seeing those as geometric objects? Even just for $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V$, given vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, does $v_1 \odot v_2$ represent some object we can visualize?

Well, an element of Sym$^2(V^*)$ is just a symmetric bilinear form, or equivalently a quadratic form, which can be visualized in terms of its level surfaces, e.g. ellipsoids or hyperboloids.

An element $X\in\bigwedge^kV$ (let's assume it's a blade) determines a linear map $V\to\bigwedge^{k+1}V,;v\mapsto X\wedge v$, and the nullspace of this map is a subspace of $V$, which uniquely corresponds to $X$ and its scalar multiples. But there's nothing analogous for $X\in$ Sym$^kV$; of course there's a linear map $V\to$ Sym$^{k+1}V,;v\mapsto X\odot v$, but it has no nullspace. $X\odot Y=0$ only if $X=0$ or $Y=0$.

For Sym$^2(V)$, I will point out that products of vectors are essentially unique: If $v_1\odot v_2=v_3\odot v_4\neq0$, then either $v_1$ is a multiple of $v_3$ and $v_2$ is a multiple of $v_4$, or $v_1$ is a multiple of $v_4$ and $v_2$ is a multiple of $v_3$. So such a product can be visualized as an (unordered) pair of lines through the origin, if we ignore scale factors.

@mr_e_man Those are very interesting comments, thanks!
